# How to display two outputs using toString() or print() etc. at the same time?

Tags: java, methods, overriding, tostring

I have a `toString()` method that I want to use to display `String.format(,)` outputs at the same time, but it doesn't happen as one output can be returned.

I tried to make another method called `print()` to get the second output, but it seems like it doesn't work even though I am explicitly calling it using the object from another class like for example:

```
Grade student = new Grade();
```

I am calling like `student.print();`

Also, in a `toString()` method I tried to do something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
return String.format("%s %d : %s %d\n",firstOutput(), firstOutput(), secondOutput(), secondOutput());
}
```

But I don't get the perfect output as expected.

Is there a way I can make two outputs to be displayed at the same time and not one at a time.

Comment: what output do you want ?It is really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The `toString()` method gets called if you use it like this:

```
System.out.println(student);
```

Thats everything you need.